# List styling issue

Tags: css, styles

I am using the following CSS

```
#basic li, #standard li, #premium li {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-image: url(../assets/misc/blue_yes.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 .5em;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
}
#high li {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-image: url(../assets/misc/green_yes.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 .5em;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
}
```

to style four separate lists

```
<ul id="basic">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
<ul id="standard">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>



<ul id="high">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>



<ul id="premium">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
```

The problem is that only the first list has the bullets removed replaced by an image. Lists 2-4 have the image alongside the bullet. How can I get all fours lists styled the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `list-style-type:none`  to the CSS code of ul's.

**Edit:**-adding code

***CSS:***

```
#basic,#standard,#premium,#high,#basic li, #standard li, #premium li,#high li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#basic,#standard,#premium,#high{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: That removes the bullet, but unlike the first list it keeps the indent as though the bullet were still there. The fist list removed the indent as well.

Comment: reset the whole ul , li . Have you considered using  reset.css ?. this will solve all your worries [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) .  For your current issue, i would suggest  `margin:0; padding:0` for ul's .

Comment: #basic, #standard, #premium, high {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

Comment: I need to figure out how to implement a reset.css I guess.

Comment: @Andy  Add it before your  normal style . Or copy paste that reset  styles on your CSS's beginning. :-) . That's it . :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class to each of the lists your styling and add css for that class rather than IDs.